# Google Analytics Views - Why Use Them?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I've been reading about Google Analytics views but still not sure why I would use them.

I'm the only person in the company who understands and uses Google Analytics. We have no subdomains. Is there any reason why I would want to use views?

Google Analytics has been going for some years now and I just created a copy of the original view but this has zero data, so I can't see how it would benefit me.

Answer (score 1):

Views are used mainly (at least from my POV) for filtered data. You can create different views for purposes like a view filtering out company IP traffic, a view of organic traffic only another view that lists the full URL of you pages and so on. You can use segments for many of the view options but when you handle complex websites with lots of traffic sources, goals and content this can simplify reports. The big drawback is the fact that data is only collected once the view is up, no historic data is available prior to that.